# SQL - How to correct the data types for all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I have been given the task to correctly detect and change the data types of all columns in a database that have been incorrectly assigned as nvarchar. The types this DB will contain are BIT, INT, DECIMAL, DATE, CHAR, and nvarchar. My first thought is to use dynamic SQL that contains a CASE. Another thought was to cycle through the types using casts and convert progressively using skips with error handling.

Comment: How do you know a nvarchar is incorrect? How do you know which data type to switch to?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The DBMS im using is SQL Server. When they imported the contents from an excel file all columns were assigned nvarchar and my task is to change them to a more appropriate data type from the following (bit, int, decimal, date, and char) assuming after this process is ran the only columns left assigned nvarchar are actually meant to be nvarchar. Doing this one column at a time is out of the question since there are hundreds of tables and thousands of columns in this DB.

Comment: I'd say, do your table data analysis, and let your script **suggest** data type changes. But let a human validate each change before altering the database.

Comment: Explain your requirement in detail and also environment.How you importing excel ?using ssis,c# etc.do you import to same table everytime.Or it is diffrent table each time?Is each time new table created.How many rows are there on average?Any other detail.Please read carefully and answer each point

Answer (score 0):

What does *correctly detect and change* mean? For NVARCHAR, I would guess it means to change the column definition to VARCHAR if all of the data already in the table can be represented as VARCHAR.  Even that is slightly vague, because the answer depends on the encoding used.  And the encodings supported by your DBMS depends on which one you're using.

So, first, make sure you know what encoding you're expected to use. Although they're not the same, frequently you'll see documentation that refers to *collation* rather than *encoding*.

Then, to guard against trouble, the safest approach is to verify the conversion can be done without losing information.  In general, if you can convert from encoding X to encoding Y and back again to X, and the value is unchanged, the conversion preserves information.

```
select A, 
       cast(A as varchar) as Av, 
       cast( cast(A as varchar) as nvarchar) ) as Avn
from T
where A <> cast( cast(A as varchar) as nvarchar) )
```

If no rows are returned, then (in SQL Server, at least) the column can be safely converted with `ALTER TABLE`.

The process *can* be automated, somewhat.  Using the system tables, you can find all columns defined as NVARCHAR.  You can generate the above code for all of them, one by one, and collect the results.  Once you're convinced the answer is correct, you can use the same information to generate `ALTER TABLE` statements or similar, as your DBMS requires.

Comment: And when you successfully have converted a name column to varchar, suddenly someone from Greece shows up and can't be stored in the database.

Comment: Thus my caveat in the 1st paragraph.  What's *correct* depends on the domain of the data stored in the column.  It would not be unusual to find a database that creates complexity by being too general.  ISO country codes, for example, don't need Unicode representation.  I suspect that is the OP's situation.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that what's stored today must not be relevant tomorrow. When in doubt, I'd go with nvarchar.

Comment: The contents of this DB was taken from an excel file and all columns of the DB where assigned as nvarchar. They want me to create an automated process that can check the columns to see if its data type is better suited as either bit, int, decimal, char, or date. Is it common for a lot of DBs to have like 90+% of its columns with data-type nvarchar?